# Docker - Stuck on "Welcome to nginx!"

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am trying to create a Docker for a PHP project. I am stuck on mapping nginx to my project files.

In my project folder root i have `dockerfile`, and `docker-composer.yml`. I also have a application folder, which contains my PHP files. (Correct setup?)

When i run `docker-compose up -d` and go to localhost, it just shows the default homepage for nginx (Welcome to nginx!) :'(

You can see my docker-compose.yml here.
docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.3'

services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - ./application:/var/www/html
    networks:
      - app

  php:
    image: php:7.1-cli
    volumes:
      - ./application:/var/www/html
    networks:
      - app

  db:
    image: mariadb:10.2
    networks:
      - app

    volumes:
     - db_data:/var/lib/mysql

networks:
  app:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
    db_data:
```